# Return a value in function with subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

I create a Util Class for some commons methods...
i try to get value from it...

```
getInfo():Info[]{
    this.subscription.add(this.generalDataService.getInfo().subscribe(
     response => {
       if (response.data != null && response.data.length > 0) {
        console.log("DATA RS1 : " + response.data);
        this.info= response.data;
       } else {
         this.info= [];
         console.log("DATA RS2 : " +  this.info);
       }    
     },
     error => {
       this.info= [];
       console.log("error in getInfo");
     }
   ));
   console.log("DATA RS3 : " +  this.info);
   return this.info;
```

}

i call this method in other class like this:

```
this.infoReturned = this.dataUtils.getInfo();
```

i need to return the array "info", but, first make the response in console "DATA RS3" and after that the subscription...
if i comment that, the function dosent compile becouse need a response..

any idea?
i try to read some like Observable or Promise, but, i'm new on angular

thnks a lot

Comment: I'm afraid your approach is using Observables all wrong. You shouldn't use subscribe callbacks: you should only use operators. Also, don't subscribe in the method: have your method return the Observable, and subscribe to it where you consume it. You also can't use Observables to populate a local variable and expect that variable to be populated synchronously as you have done here. May I suggest following an RxJS tutorial of some kind? You seem to be lacking the necessary understanding of asynchronous code.

Comment: I'm saying all of the above in the friendliest way possible :-) I'm not insinuating anything about your other abilities; simply saying that a basic understanding of async code and Observables would be of great benefit to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it to promise and wait for is :

```
async getInfo():Info[]{
 const res = await this.generalDataService.getInfo().toPromise()
 return res || []
}
```